# GET request from for loop not pushing to MongoDB, database still empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to send data from my for loop up to my MongoDB. When I run the js file from console, `node initCount.js` everything seems fine and I do not "errors" thrown back in my console. However, when I head back over to my MongoDB backend, my collection is still empty, no data has been sent. What am I doing wrong? This is what I am expecting to see back in my database:

`[ { "i": 1, "iSquared": 2 }, { "i": 2, "iSquared": 4 }, { "i": 3, "iSquared" 6 }...]`

**My Code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://${USERNAME}@cluster0.2h2xb.mongodb.net/${PATH}?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const Num = require("./number");
client.connect((err) => {
  const numberline = client.db("numberline").collection("Num");
  console.log(numberline);
  client.close();
});

const app = express();

app.get("/add-num", (req, res) => {
  const number = new Num({
    i: 1,
    iSquared: 2,
  })
    .then((result) => {
      res.send(result);
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

  let inputNum = 100;

// For loop takes in a number and pushes a count up to the DB's number line.

  for (let i = 0; i <= inputNum; i++) {
      const iSquared = i + i;
      number
        .save({ i, iSquared })
        .then((result) => {
          res.send(result);
          console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
  }
```

**Number Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const numberSchema = new Schema({
  i: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
  },
  frequency: {
    type: Number,
    require: true,
  },
});

const Num = mongoose.model("Num", numberSchema);
module.exports = Num;
```

**Console Output**

```
Collection {
  s: {
    pkFactory: <ref *1> [Function: ObjectID] {
      index: 2405507,
      createPk: [Function: createPk],
      createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
      createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
      isValid: [Function: isValid],
      ObjectID: [Circular *1],
      ObjectId: [Circular *1]
    },
    db: Db {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      s: [Object],
      serverConfig: [Getter],
      bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
      databaseName: [Getter],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    topology: ReplSet {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 35,
      _maxListeners: Infinity,
      s: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    options: {
      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
      readConcern: undefined,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference]
    },
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'numberline', collection: 'Num' },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined
    },
    slaveOk: true,
    serializeFunctions: undefined,
    raw: undefined,
    promoteLongs: undefined,
    promoteValues: undefined,
    promoteBuffers: undefined,
    internalHint: null,
    collectionHint: null,
    promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
    readConcern: undefined,
    writeConcern: undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many mistakes in your code, from connection to db and use models in your route, but I changed your code, and now you can do implementation of your business logic

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Num = require('./Num');//path of Num model
const app = express();
const uri =
 "mongodb+srv://${USERNAME}@cluster0.2h2xb.mongodb.net/${PATH}?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose
  .connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(3000);
    console.log("connected to db and server port is 3000");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.get("/add-num", async (req, res) => {
  let inputNum = 100;

  let reuslt = [];
  var list =  var list = Array.from({length:inputNum },(v,k)=>k+1) //from 1 upto 100
  for (let i of list) {
    const iSquared = i + i;
    const number = new Num({
      i: i,
      iSquared,
    });
    try {
      let output = await number.save();
      reuslt.push(output);
      console.log(output.toObject())// new model
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  res.status(200).json({reuslt})// all models
});
```

use `for of` with `async/await` instead of `for`

you can not passing argument to the `save` function

in the Num Model `frequency` is defined so you can try like this

```
const number = new Num({
      i: i,
      iSquared,
 });
```

when you want connect to the db you can use async/await or .then .catch

```
mongoose
  .connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then((result) => {
    app.listen(3000);//if connect to db successfully, listen to 3000 port
    console.log("connected to db and server port is 3000");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

change the name of field `frequency` to `iSquared` and `required: true` is correct validation not `require : true`

**Num.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const numberSchema = new Schema({
  i: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  iSquared: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Num = mongoose.model("Num", numberSchema);
module.exports = Num;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution!! I've been coding all day, so I really appreciate this. Could you help me with one more thing? I'm getting an err in my console saying it, " Cannot find module './Num' ". I checked the names and everything seems all consistent. Any clue?

Comment: it's the Num schema, I put the schema in Num.js and require in to the app.js